# I need 4 If Statements and then 1 single else statmen if all of them are true

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

As you may know I am very new to iOS development and have a very specific question. I need to write an `if ... else` statement that has four conditions in the if, and only then the actual action will be performed. So I need to do something like this:

If (Condition1 + Condition2 + Condition3 + Condition4)
then 
{THE ACTUAL ACTION}
else
…………………

When I tried

```
-(IBAction)Buttontouched: (id) sender;
{
    if (NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField1.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"teacher"]){
        if (NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField2.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Maths"]){
            if (NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField3.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"english"]){
                if (NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField4.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"greek"]){
                    NumberCount = NumberCount +5;
                    ErrorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have achived %i out of 50 points", >NumberCount];
                    April1.hidden = true;
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

It didn't work….. Please help me!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to execute the code if _any_ of the comparisons is true? Right now, you're requiring them _all_ to be true at once, which is hard since `self.InputField1.text` can only have a single value and you're requiring it to be equal to 4 different values at once.

Comment: Oh god…. I'm so sorry my mistake… I forgot to exchange the numbers. It's 4 different Input fields…..

Comment: Odd though - I can't see why your implementation you posted (with the correctly given property names) doesn't work, you are doing effectively the same thing.

Comment: Where is the `else` in your code?  What _exactly_ do you mean by "it didn't work"?  What happens or doesn't happen that you expected or didn't expect?  Is this your actual code because the ">NumberCount" in the stringWithFormat line will not compile.  What debugging have you done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this which will only proceed if all 4 statements are true.

```
-(IBAction)Buttontouched: (id) sender {
    if ((NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField1.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"teacher"]) &&
        (NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField2.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Maths"]) &&
        (NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField3.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"english"]) &&
        (NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField4.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"greek"])) 
    {     
        NumberCount = NumberCount +5; 
        ErrorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have achived %i out of 50 points", >NumberCount]; 
        April1.hidden = true;
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try and accept in within 2h, because I have to go! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. They are called logical operators in case you didn't know. There are some examples about halfway down this page  http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: @user3527280 this answer provides an equivalent to your code, just better readable but exactly the same. If your code does not work then neither this will work nor will AlieN's solution work, because the all are equivalent. I guess your input fields don't carry the desired content or the IBOutlets, if any, are not properly connected. Check on that. And btw, the inputFieldX should start with a lower case I. The same for the method buttonTouched and the variables numberconut, errorLable and apil1.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField1.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"teacher"])&&(NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField2.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Maths"])&&(NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField3.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"english"])&&(NSOrderedSame == [self.InputField4.text caseInsensitiveCompare:@"greek"]))
{
// your code here
}
else
{
//another code here
}
```

Comment: The author seems to want AND rather than OR.

Comment: @AlieN you probably want to change the property names.

Comment: I've already told you why the answer is wrong - not your fault, but the question has been updated. You need to use `InputField1`, `InputField2`, etc.

Comment: @Rich Understood)))))